MathJax refuses to compile a specific class of commands
I recently opened a blog in blogger.com to mainly write about short math snippets. To do so, I had to edit HTML and add MathJax. After some googling, I figured out (maybe wrongly) that the way people do it is by copying the following code :-
<script src='https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6'/>
<script async='async' id='MathJax-script' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script>
window.MathJax = {
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [ [&#39;$&#39;,&#39;$&#39;],[&#39;\\(&#39;,&#39;\\)&#39;] ],
    displayMath: [ [&#39;$$&#39;,&#39;$$&#39;], [&#39;\\[&#39;,&#39;\\]&#39;] ],
    processEscapes: true,      
    processEnvironments: true, 
    processRefs: true       
  },
  options: {
   ignoreHtmlClass: &#39;tex2jax_ignore|editor-rich-text&#39;
  }
};
</script>

While it initially felt like this worked, soon I realized that commands of the form
\begin{equation}
...
\end{equation}

aren't getting compiled, although those of the form
$$ .. $$

or even
\[ .. \]

works absolutely fine.
I was managing this with some hrdships until I realised that even
$$\begin{cases}
...
\end{cases}$$

and (even worse)
$$\begin{bmatrix}
...
\end{bmatrix}$$

aren't working. In brief, any command of the form \begin{blah}...\end{blah} doesn't compile.
I guess this is not a blogger.com problem since I have seen many other posts where equations are very well aligned. I have tried every "silly method" that I knew to fix it. But it seems the problem is deeper somewhere. I will be glad if someone can help me out. Please note that I am not a tech savvy person - so the answer to the question might very simply be my own stupidity.
Here's a screenshot of the first few lines of HTML in case that helps :-

Also posted on Stack Overflow - in case you want to write an answer but can't (since the post is closed).

unfortunately, MathJax is off-topic here as it does not use TeX at all.

but never post screenshots of code. always post code as plain text.

Are you including the Ams stuff in your loading? The url we normally load normally looks different (we're not using the latest version though). Besides, I agree, this is off topic here as not having anything to do with text and friends

@cfr initially I thought so. Then I checked that there is a mathjax tag here - so it might be relevant. Do you have any suggestions to improve the question to make it on topic here? Also, the code was way too long to post here as a text - the screenshot was included only to make sure that nothing was wrong in my copy-pasting the mathjax part in the HTML.

@daleif I'm sorry I don't understand your comment. You will have to break "Ams stuff" down to me - I'm extremely stupid when it comes down to matters of this kind (and in general, now that I think about it).

@SayanDutta If you notice that a specific tag exists on a site, please read the tag description. If often gives hints to what extend questions are on- or off-topic: https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/mathjax/info

Now I tested your setup. If I replace those &#39; by ' then it works just fine, including $...$ and \begin{equation}...\end{equation} as well as the other examples you gave.

@daleif you did mean all of the &#39's right? Turns out I can't do it. Every time I'm trying to save those changes, the system autosaves ```
``` (continued in next comment)
window.MathJax = {
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [ [&#39;;$&#39;;,&#39;;$&#39;;],[&#39;;\\(&#39;;,&#39;;\\)&#39;;] ],
    displayMath: [ [&#39;;$$&#39;;,&#39;;$$&#39;;], [&#39;;\\[&#39;;,&#39;;\\]&#39;;] ],
    processEscapes: true,      
    processEnvironments: true, 
    processRefs: true       
  },
  options: {
   ignoreHtmlClass: &#39;;tex2jax_ignore|editor-rich-text&#39;;
  }
};
</script>```

@daleif also, with the version that gets autosaved, only the commands $$..$$ works and $..$ doesn't
